# Security in Offline Hybrid Application

Tags: javascript, java, android, sqlite, encryption

We have a **hybrid offline application** that have sensitive information that is encrypted but gets decrypted on App so the user can see the results. The key is stored in Javascript and can be accessed by pressing F12 in chrome or getting the code from mobile devices and beautifying it.

I have gone through a lot of articles and as well questions here at Stackoverflow. What I understood is it's not possible to secure anything in Javascript, the best you can do is Minify or Obfuscate.

I read a article about Android Keystore which looks promising but if I pass my key from Java to Javascript to decrypt data coming from my SQLite DB, it will again raise security concerns.

Here is my question, Can I **encrypt my SQLite DB** in javascript, I know it's possible from Java. Also, what will be the best possible solution to this problem ?

Also, if I do all my DB operations at Java and pass values to javascript, how much will be the perfomance get hit?

I know its a bit of a rant but I needed to explain my use case properly. Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Anything that reaches the browser is not secure and can be tampered with

Comment: What is the difference between a value in the database and something shown on the screen? The only way of keeping the key secret is to not store it on the device, i.e., letting the user input it every time the app runs (which leads to other problems).

Comment: Its an offline App. Also, the user has to login in the App to see the decrypted values from DB. DB values are all encrypted.